# YUI Datatable -- how to mark row as modified?

Tags: datatable, yui3

I'm using YUI 3.7.3, and have an instance of a DataTable. The rows in the table are represented by 'Session' objects, and the values shown in the table columns are derived from an internal list in each Session object (i.e., I specify 'formatter' for each column.) When new data is added to the internal list (basically, updated session state), I'd like to be able to tell the DataTable that the row needs to be marked dirty/redisplayed. But how? DataTable.modifyRow() doesn't seem to do it, since I'm not actually modifying a direct attribute of the Session objects--I'm adding data to a sub-list of the Session.

What's the recommended way to tell DataTable that a particular row needs to be redisplayed?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to indicate that a single row's record requires re-rendering. You could attempt simulating the [change](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Model.html#event_change) event on the Model in question.

```
var table = new Y.DataTable({
  columns: [
    { key: 'obj', label: 'nested', formatter: function (o) { return o.value.nested; } }
  ],
  data: [ {obj: {nested: 42}} ]
}).render('#table'), row = table.getRecord(0), data = row.get('obj');

data.nested = 47;
row.fire('change', { changed: { prevVal: data, newVal: data } });
```

Depending on how closely you want to imitate the [Model:change](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Model.html#event_change) event, you may want to perform a deep copy of your data before altering it, then passing that as the prevVal.
For the purposes of updating the DataTable view, this does not seem to matter, as you could have just as well done this:

```
row.fire('change');
```

The result would have been the same. This is fragile, and it is likely not how the interface was intended to be used. However, if all you need to accomplish is update the view after changing the internal state, as opposed to firing off any change-related events, then [DataTable.syncUI](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#method_syncUI) is a much more elegant solution.

```
var table = new Y.DataTable({
  columns: [
    { key: 'obj', label: 'nested', formatter: function (o) { return o.value.nested; } }
  ],
  data: [ {obj: {nested: 42}} ]
}).render('#table'), row = table.getRecord(0), data = row.get('obj');

data.nested = 47;
table.syncUI();
```

With this, you can perform all of your data manipulation, then call `syncUI` when you want to redraw, as opposed to firing for each row modified. Hope this helps.